# SQL checking if a value is an empty string?

Tags: sql

This is the where clause of my query:

```
WHERE person.personstatusuid = @StatusUID
           AND person.forename != ''
```

this works fine - @StatusUID is coming from a drop down box.

However, I also have a location field. This code works fine too:

WHERE person.personstatusuid = @StatusUID
           AND person.forename != ''
           AND person.Location = @Location

I want to change the last line to be if it is the @Location (which comes from a text box) or the @Location is empty.

I tried using an OR as was suggested, but no matter what I try, it does not return any rows. I have tried replacing the line with this, just for testing purposes:

```
   AND (@Location NOT LIKE 'BISCUITS' )

   AND (@Location!='' )

   AND (LEN(@Location) == 0 )
```

but none of them work when I leave the text box blank.

Any ideas?

Comment: I swear to god I tried that, but can anyone explain why @Location='' doesnt work even when @Location is an empty string? I even made sure ConvertEmptyStringsToNull was FALSE...

Comment: What environment is that? That isn't standard SQL, right? Could someone please retag this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
WHERE   person.personstatusuid = @StatusUID 
AND     person.forename != '' 
AND     (ISNULL(@Location,'') = '' OR person.Location = @Location)
```